# Sencha Touch query

Tags: sencha-touch

how I add querystring in sencha touch?

?name=jake as

localhost/JSONDemo/XMLToJson.aspx?name=jake

My code is

```
Ext.regStore('NewsItems', {

    model: 'NewsItem',

       proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'XMLToJson.aspx', 
        reader: { 
            type: 'json',
            root: 'liste.dokuman'
        }
    },

    autoLoad: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters using the `extraParams` property available with your proxy object. Here is an example:

```
 Ext.regStore('NewsItems', {

    model: 'NewsItem',

       proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'XMLToJson.aspx', 
        extraParams: {
              name: 'jack'
        },
        reader: { 
            type: 'json',
            root: 'liste.dokuman'
        }
    },

    autoLoad: true
});
```